# Rails makevoteable help creating user voting link and custom error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am having that problem with the gem makevoteable that when the page is loaded the post gets upvoted automatic. Instead of just having a link the user can click and upvote. When the page is reloaded I get the AlreadyVotedError in view. I would prefer a more user friendly error message as "You already voted this post"

My view:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <h1><%= post.titel %></h1>
  <p><%= post.body_html %></p>
  <p><%= link_to 'asdasdasd', current_user.up_vote(post) %>
<% end %>
```

UPDATE:

My route.rb: `match 'stem_op/:id' => 'posts#vote_up', :as => 'stem_op'`

My public controller:

```
def vote_up
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  current_user.up_vote(@post)
  flash[:message] = 'Thanks for voting!'
  redirect_to post_path(@post)
rescue MakeVoteable::Exceptions::AlreadyVotedError
  flash[:error] = 'Already voted!'
  redirect_to post_path(@post)
end
```

My view:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <h1><%= post.titel %></h1>
  <p><%= post.body_html %></p>
  <p><%= link_to 'Stem op', stem_op_path(post.id) %> 
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

When I try to vote_up a post I get this error:

Template missing - Do I really need a blank view file?

UPDATE:

```
def vote_up
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  current_user.up_vote(@post)
  flash[:message] = 'Thanks for voting!'
  redirect_to post_path(@post)
rescue MakeVoteable::Exceptions::AlreadyVotedError
  flash[:error] = 'Already voted!'
  redirect_to post_path(@post)
end
```

Error:

```
SyntaxError in PostsController#vote_up

C:/Rails/den/app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:103: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting $end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `current_user.up_vote(post)` adds a vote for that user. You need to create a controller action that executes `current_user.up_vote(post)` and handles the flash message.  Then you can link to that action in your view.

Edit to answer comment:

[guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#methods-and-actions)

In your posts controller I imagine you would want something like:

```
def upvote
  @post = Post.find params[:id]
  current_user.upvote(@post)
  flash[:message] = 'Thanks for voting!'
  redirect_to post_path(@post)
rescue MakeVoteable::Exceptions::AlreadyVotedError
  flash[:error] = 'Already voted!'
  redirect_to post_path(@post)
end
```

and in your routes something like:

```
map.resource :post do
  member do
    post :upvote
  end
end
```

Your link would become `link_to 'Upvote!', upvote_post_url(post), :method => :post`

Comment: How do I create the flash error message for the :AlreadyVotedError? And do I really need a blank view file for the vote_up action?

Comment: I have tried your code(there was a few typos) I have posted my action in my qustion I get a  unexpected keyword_end

Comment: My mistake ... had removed a end in the end